# Bonding two broadband connections to serve LAN as a gateway

Tags: networking, iptables, bonding

I need to increase the connectivity and speed of the Internet to my LAN users. These are the things I have in my hand to do so.

1. PC with 3 NICs 1 for LAN and 2 for routers
2. 2 broadband connections with dynamic IPs connected to two routers. (one with 192.168.1.1 and one with 192.168.0.1)
3. CentOs 6.4

I need My Eth0 to serve my LAN users as below:

Eth0 Ip: 192.168.100.250 and this should be their gateway and DNS to the Internet (Correct me if this wrong)

I use each router's Lan IPs as gateways and DNSs as;
Eth1 IP: 192.168.0.250, Gateway 192.168.0.1, DNS 192.168.0.1 
Eth2 Ip: 192.168.1.250, Gateway 192.168.1.1, DNS 192.168.1.1

But how do I configure Bonding?
Do I need to assign IP settings before the configuration of bonding?
should I change LAN ip addresses of routers to one/same segmant/subnet as 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2?
If I config the bonding, what should be my Eth0 configuration? Leave it as it is?
What is the most suitable bonding mode for a LAN more than 50 users?

Comment: See this Q&A, shows how to do this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62425/bonded-network-interface-is-not-available-after-a-reboot/63184#63184

Comment: Another thread that shows how to do this: http://forums.cpanel.net/f189/guide-spreading-bandwidth-across-two-nics-bonding-centos-6-4-final-354152.html

Comment: Also this step by step tutorial is what you're looking for: http://geekpeek.net/centos-network-bonding/

Comment: In general bonding does not make your connections faster, just gives you more lanes on the highway. Bonding the devices would make 2 NICs share the same IP as well. The bonding interface (often named br0) will own the IP and the 2 NICs under it will not have any IPs associated to them.

Answer (score 3):

Ethernet bonding is not the solution here. Bonding is a Layer-2 feature, and you are running Layer-3 (IP) on your routers.

I assume that your routers are connected to different ISP endpoints.

What I would do:

1. Remove the two routers from the configuration, and configure ISP networks directly on your PC with 3 NICs. That is:

   - NIC 1: 192.168.100.250
   - NIC 2: ISP #1 public IP
   - NIC 3: ISP #2 public IP
2. Make NAT rules so that traffic from source ports 1-32767 are NATed to first outgoing connection public IP, and from source ports 32768-65535 are NATed to second outgoing connection public IP. With this configuration you will get a basic load-balancing configuration.

EDIT: You might also need to apply some policy routing here, because NAT is done after routing decision, therefore the packet would still be routed to the wrong interface.

[multigateway routing for specific src port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/multigateway-routing-for-specific-src-port) has clear instructions on how to apply policy routing based on source port.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as Tero suggested in part 1 (configuring with public IP may not be necessary but I configured the NICs with the public addresses.) With regard to part 2 I think there must be a better way of doing this but not sure how. What I want to add is regards policy routing since the link given is not specifically for this situation, and also regarding masquerading which I don't think has been mentioned.
Add the lines

```
1   isp1
2   isp2
```

to /etc/iproute2/rt_tables.

Then:

```
ip addr add 192.168.100.250 dev eth0
ip addr add 192.168.0.250 dev eth1
ip addr add 192.168.1.250 dev eth2
```

(if these aren't already configured) then

```
iptables-save > IptablesSaveFile
```

then edit this file so it looks something like

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT
:INPUT ACCEPT
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING ! -d 192.168.100.0/24 -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.250
-A POSTROUTING ! -d 192.168.100.0/24 -o eth2 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.250
-A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
... your iptables filtering rules here ...
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth2 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

then

```
iptables-restore < IptablesSaveFile
```

to activate the firewall (masquerading) rules. Then

```
ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0 table isp1
ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0 table isp2
ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1 table isp1
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth1 table isp1
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth2 table isp2
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth2 table isp2
ip rule add from 192.168.0.250 table isp1
ip rule add from 192.168.1.250 table isp2
```

The above is so that connections coming in on one interface are returned on the  same interface.  I had a DNS server running on the machine this was set up on so users could just connect to 192.168.100.250 - if you don't I'm not sure of the best way of doing this - you could possible set up a stub resolver which switches between the 2 DNS address to forward requests or set up half the users machines to use one DNS address and the other half the other.